# C++ what happens to a value that is returned but is not stored?

Tags: c++, function, return, return-value

Say I have a function that returns an `int`. I don't store the value from the function call. I presume that it is not stored in memory and fades into the aether, but I don't know.
Thank you.

Comment: Well, that value will cease to exist as with any value when a function goes out of scope. At the place of using that function without receiving this value, there won't be any code generated to copy it elsewhere.

Comment: I don't understand the close votes. The question is perfectly clear.

Comment: @CareyGregory No, the question isn't clearly written (what should be _the aether_ actually, or what kind of value is meant (variable, constant) for example), and lacks some concrete code samples. There are many possibilities how the compiler could handle that situation actually, including optimizing the whole function call away in some situations (as mentioned in Jerry's answer). You may consider editing and improve it though.

Comment: It's gone, man, solid gone..

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ actually the upvoted answer proves it's clear enough to be answered. Also - as far as I remember from my high school physics classes - _aether_ in this case should be understood as _void_.

Comment: @PawełStawarz Getting good answers, doesn't prove for good questions. Not everything that could be answered should be necessarily. Judging questions and answers are different kettle of fish, and thus are handled separately by means of down & close voting (I actually upvoted the answer myself).

Comment: It is a simple question that I wanted (and received) some insight to, why is this causing such a commotion...

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ The question is perfectly clear. The (luminiferous)aether was a, now discarded, physical theory. Now aether is more commonly used as a tool to describe the empty space, sometimes referred to as the void. This should not discredit the question. One can easily deduce the gist without this trivia. It is however a duplicate (see related), and should be closed. It should be noted that Jerry Coffin also answered that question, not the accepted answer though. I find his and this accepted answer to hit the spot.

Comment: @CaptainGiraffe I well know what _aether_ actually means. It's just not very clear to use this metaphor, for a concrete computing related question (or why do you think that Kerrek's sarcastic comment was upvoted so much?). Jerry Coffin's answer is the accepted one BTW, I don't get what you're saying there.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ SB is clever and funny; building on the "replacing smoke" in a broken PDU's . That's why I clicked it anyhow. I did not find it sarcastic. On the other hand my sarcasm meter have broken several times, so that's also a factor.

Comment: Whether the OP's first language is English or not, it doesn't matter if his choice of phrases and metaphors is entirely appropriate as long as we can understand the question, and it seems that most of us can. If you can't, then do something useful and edit the question.

Comment: The speed of sarcasm is a universal constant, the same for all observers.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

An `int` return value will normally be stored in a register (e.g., EAX or RAX on 32-bit or 64-bit Intel, respectively).

It won't fade. It'll simply be overwritten when the compiler needs that register for some other purpose. If the function in question is expanded inline, the compiler may detect that the value isn't used, and elide the code to write or compute the value at all.